# Is there a setting through which a code review request can be sent to a group directly?

Tags: tfs, tfs-code-review

I have just started using TFS code review plugin and it looks good.

I wanted to know if there is any such setting through which a code review request can be sent to a group directly { not adding each member manually }

Prior to that would be another question. Can we have a group level setting in TFS. Like we have in outlook and other applications.

Comment: Maybe this post can help you out: http://ivanfioravanti.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/assigning-a-work-item-to-a-group-in-tfs/

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to have Collaborator for that. TFS's code review functionality is not that powerful...